# Symfony 4 - PHP 7.3 - Error in Authentication/Token/AbstractToken.php

Tags: php, symfony

in my project Symfony 4, when I go on some pages, I have deserialization bugs of the token, which causes me this error:

> Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 11282 of 17034 bytes

[image]

I noticed that I was not the only one with this problem:

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/29459

To work around the problem I just implemented Serializable in my User entity by selecting only certain attributes. But it's not a good solution to do that, I really want to fix the real problem without pushing it away.

In another topic with the same kind of problem, a solution has been made: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/29951#issuecomment-457626478

But that means I'm going to have to edit a very important file, and that's not a good solution I think. Does someone have an idea ? Should I go back to PHP 7.2?

Comment: If you think its a Symfont bug report it and get a fix

Comment: It seems that it is reported : https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/29459#issuecomment-447551270 but no response

Comment: Try go back to PHP 7.2 or check PHP7.4

Comment: I downgraded to 7.2.19, it's semm better yes !

Comment: You should use `php7.2` or `php7.4`

Comment: Yes I use php 7.2 now ans it's okay