# Symony 5 WDT / Profiler toolbar unserialze error

Tags: php, symfony

I always get the folloing error with the WDT. The profiler toolbar show only: An error occurred while loading the web debug toolbar. Symfony log is below:

> [Web Server ] Apr 21 22:11:16 |DEBUG  | PHP    Reloading PHP versions
> [Web Server ] Apr 21 22:11:16 |DEBUG  | PHP    Using PHP version 8.0.3 (from default version in $PATH)

> [Application] Apr 21 22:09:39 |DEBUG  | DOCTRI SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table' AND name != 'sqlite_sequence' AND name != 'geometry_columns' AND name != 'spatial_ref_sys' UNION ALL SELECT name FROM sqlite_temp_master WHERE type = 'table' ORDER BY name

> [Application] Apr 21 22:09:39 |INFO   | REQUES Matched route "_wdt". method="GET" request_uri="https://127.0.0.1:8000/_wdt/737bae" route="_wdt" route_parameters={"_controller":"web_profiler.controller.profiler::toolbarAction","_route":"_wdt","token":"737bae"}

> [Application] Apr 21 22:09:39 |CRITICA| REQUES Uncaught PHP Exception ErrorException: "Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 62001 of 62050 bytes" at /media/storage/Clouds/Dropbox/Workspaces/web/txtadventures/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Profiler/FileProfilerStorage.php line 126

> [Application] Apr 21 22:09:39 |ERROR  | REQUES Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No route found for "GET /favicon.ico" (from "https://127.0.0.1:8000/")" at /media/storage/Clouds/Dropbox/Workspaces/web/txtadventures/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php line 136

> [Application] Apr 21 22:09:39 |DEBUG  | DOCTRI SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table' AND name != 'sqlite_sequence' AND name != 'geometry_columns' AND name != 'spatial_ref_sys' UNION ALL SELECT name FROM sqlite_temp_master WHERE type = 'table' ORDER BY name

> [Application] Apr 21 22:09:39 |DEBUG  | DOCTRI SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table' AND name != 'sqlite_sequence' AND name != 'geometry_columns' AND name != 'spatial_ref_sys' UNION ALL SELECT name FROM sqlite_temp_master WHERE type = 'table' ORDER BY name
> [Application] Apr 21 22:09:39 |DEBUG  | DOCTRI SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table' AND name != 'sqlite_sequence' AND name != 'geometry_columns' AND name != 'spatial_ref_sys' UNION ALL SELECT name FROM sqlite_temp_master WHERE type = 'table' ORDER BY name

> [Application] Apr 21 22:09:39 |DEBUG  | DOCTRI SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table' AND name != 'sqlite_sequence' AND name != 'geometry_columns' AND name != 'spatial_ref_sys' UNION ALL SELECT name FROM sqlite_temp_master WHERE type = 'table' ORDER BY name

> [Application] Apr 21 22:09:39 |DEBUG  | DOCTRI SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table' AND name != 'sqlite_sequence' AND name != 'geometry_columns' AND name != 'spatial_ref_sys' UNION ALL SELECT name FROM sqlite_temp_master WHERE type = 'table' ORDER BY name

> [Application] Apr 21 22:09:39 |DEBUG  | DOCTRI SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table' AND name != 'sqlite_sequence' AND name != 'geometry_columns' AND name != 'spatial_ref_sys' UNION ALL SELECT name FROM sqlite_temp_master WHERE type = 'table' ORDER BY name

> [Web Server ] Apr 21 22:11:16 |INFO   | PHP    listening path="/usr/bin/php8.0" php="8.0.3" port=35977

> [PHP        ] [Wed Apr 21 22:11:16 2021] PHP 8.0.3 Development Server (http://127.0.0.1:35977) started

Nothing changed anything. The app is also a clean project, with only basics installed.
Downloadable project at: [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9vnmzceen233gfb/txtadventures-copy.zip?dl=1)

Got the same error with PHP 7.4 and PHP 8.0 using the symfony build-in server.
Any ideas how to solve this.

Comment: Some searches are showing it is an encoding issue. You will probably have to debug that specific line of code, possibly editing it directly in `vendor` to see what is in.

Comment: I will try IT. Questions is, why IT happens on a fresh instsll

Comment: I've got the same error. Seems to be an issue with the encoding of some files. I haven't a solution yet.

Comment: You are going to have to edit `/media/storage/Clouds/Dropbox/Workspaces/web/txtadventures/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Profiler/FileProfilerStorage.php`, line 126. Somehow you are going to have to log each `$file` that is trying to be read, and then find which one specifically is tripping this up, and then inspect that specific file. In the log that you've posted, you'd want to inspect byte `62001` but it might be different next time you run. Are you running this all on a dropbox share, btw? If so, maybe a sync is happening and you should try running 100% local-only, too.

Answer (score 0):

At its core this seems to be an error in php which has been fixed with php-7.4.

[official php issue](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/custom_object_serialization)

It is related to \Serializable Interface (serialize()/unserialize() object methods) and __sleep()/__wakeup magic method implementation.

It seems that with the new magic methods __serialize/__unserialize one can avoid this problem.

In my case it seemed solved by updating to the recent php-7.4.24 but i refactored my projects use of \Serializable to __serialize/__unserialize (in user objects) anyway to definitely get rid of the officialy underlying issue.

Other resources i utilized along the way (more or less related):

- https://3v4l.org/gTumn
- https://github.com/symfony/security-guard/blob/5.3/Token/PostAuthenticationGuardToken.php
- https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=77302
- https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/29459
- [Symfony 4 - PHP 7.3 - Error in Authentication/Token/AbstractToken.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59290185/symfony-4-php-7-3-error-in-authentication-token-abstracttoken-php?noredirect=1#comment104790059_59290185)
- https://github.com/mangelio/app/blob/php-bug-%2377302/README.BUG77302.md
- https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/issues/10223

Comment: thx, I will test it.